What is an Inaugural Fund?
There was a news today about Meta, Amazon donating to Donald Trump's inaugural fund.
What is an inaugural fund? Is it official/constitutional? Is the president considered accountable for its usage? Is it considered charity?

Apparently the "inaugural fund" is the fund that is raised by the Presidential Inaugural committee:

This committee is the legal entity responsible for fundraising for and the planning and coordination of all official events and activities surrounding the inauguration of president and vice president (other than the ceremony), such as the balls and parade.


Since 1901, the Joint Committee on Inaugural Ceremonies has been responsible for the planning and execution of the swearing-in ceremonies. Since 1953, it has also hosted a luncheon at the U.S. Capitol for the new president, vice president, and guests. Three senators and three representatives make up the committee.

So they essentially just host the festivities for the inaugural event. And the president elect apparently names the members of the committee. This is apparently first recognized by law as early as 1881. So somewhat of an official tradition.
According to this Alliance of Justice the organization is a 501(c)(4) organization.
And it doesn't seem to be a charitable cause that is tax deductible, though might count as business expenses:

Contributions to 501(c)(4) organizations are not tax-deductible as charitable donations unless the organization is either a volunteer fire department or a veterans organization. Dues or contributions to 501(c)(4) organizations may be deductible as a business expense under IRC 162, although amounts paid for intervention or participation in any political campaign, direct lobbying, grass roots lobbying, and contact with certain federal officials are not deductible. If a 501(c)(4) engages in a substantial number of these activities, then only the amount of dues or contributions that can be attributed to other activities may be deductible as a business expense.

Here are some addition FEC info on the committee and the reporting of do.
Not sure the Presidents job goes beyond appointing and helping them organize his party, but yeah accountability has been an issue lately. When Trump held a modest party but spend a record breaking amount of money on it, including lavish bills for Hotels that he owns...
According to that link Trumps spend 104 million dollars on his last inauguration while Obama's first inauguration amounted to 53 million dollars.
The difference according to opensecrets.org seems to be that:

Of course, Obama in 2009 (though not in 2013) barred corporate, labor, PAC and lobbyist contributions and individual gifts of more than $50,000; Trump set no dollar limit and prohibited contributions only from lobbyists. Another difference? The menu of choices offered to donors, where specific dollar values were attached to different levels of access. Admission to a "leadership luncheon" with members of Trump's cabinet and GOP congressional leaders was on offer for a cool $1 million, for example.

 So while I haven't found the perk list for this year as the news are spammed by those 1 million dollar donations, it's very likely that this also seems to be a specific tier of perks for donations where they get special access to the president and the ministers for example at the official luncheon as apparently happened in 2017. According to axios (point 6) amounts to 6 tickets for all the Inaugural events.
Also the website seems to list who the donors are and what they donated. Now from what I can see neither Besoz nor Zuckerberg or their respective companies have donated to Obama's inauguration in 2009 or 2013, Amazon has donated in 2017 but less than a million and I can't find Meta or Facebook.
If I've missed something please mention it in the comments or suggest an edit.

It would be interesting to see how much they donated to Obama's inaugural committee. According to the article, Biden's did not accept donations, at least from technology companies, and they donated only about USD 57,000 after Trump's first election, which is a very different amount (but still far from nothing). Anyway, knowing how much they donated to Obama would give us a better idea of whether the 2017 donation was an anomaly in a general pattern of
quid (if not pro quo) , or whether the 2021 donations are because CEOs actually like Trump more now.

Your last link has some useful context information, namely 'But the amount of money involved was record-breaking – with more than $107 million raised and $104 million spent, double the amounts of President Barack Obama’s first inaugural.' So the total budget of the committee was $107m for Trumps first inaugeration and around $50m for Obamas first inaugeration.

Great answer, just missed an explanation of the grift part: how does the President get kickbacks from all of this? Or is the party itself the kickback and nothing else is needed?

@JonathanReez I guess the original kickback is just the party and the prestige, which is likely why there's little restriction on the donations, but John Sarbanes argued that without transparency that's basically a slush fund for all sorts of expenses. And apparently 1.5 million went to one Trump owned Hotel despite also booking 2 other hotels. 2.7 millions went to a company of his campaign manager and 26 million to a friend of Melania despite also hiring professionals for those jobs as well. The IRS is supposed to be behind using that for enrichment but there seem to be options.

@JonathanReez Funding campaigns and events where the principal politician has restrictions on spending will rarely, if ever, have direct kickbacks to the politician. To corruptly use an event like the inaugural fund the donors to the fund are the ones making payouts to people on behalf of the politician. Example being the donor pays for a favor from the politician by funding the politician purchasing or paying off favors to others. If the politician wants cash kickbacks, a common method is to publish a book.
